# Convergence of a Closed Subset Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose C is a closed subset of $R^n$ and $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in C. Prove: Either the sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ does not converge to any point of $R^n$ or it converges to a point in C.

Comment: What is your definition of "closed"? The proof would be just one line for some definition.

Comment: If $x_n\to x\in R^n$, and $x\in C^c$, then there are elements of $x_n\in C^c$, since $C^c$ is open. But the $x_n\in C$, which is a contradiction with also belonging to $C^c$. Therefore, either $x_n\to x\in R^n$ is false or such an $x$ exists but $x\in C$ is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} x_m = x \in \Bbb R^n \setminus C.$$

Then because $C$ is closed, $\Bbb R^n \setminus C$ is open, so $\exists \text{ open } U \subseteq \Bbb R^n \setminus C \text{ with } x \in U.$  Choose $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that $B(x, \varepsilon) \subseteq U$.  Choose $M$ such that $m \gt M \Rightarrow \vert x - x_m \vert \lt \varepsilon$.  Then $m \gt M \Rightarrow x_m \in U \Rightarrow x_m \notin C$, contradicting our assumption that $\forall m ~ x_m \in C$.  This, if the limit exists, it must lie in $C$.